# How set the default scaling factor for importing and exporting to be equivalent to real world scale? How to change the defaults?

Tags: python, transforms, 3d-printing

Ok, this doesn't seem to be a new problem, but I am looking for a new solution. I use blender for both printing in the real world and visualizing and simulating. For a long time I did like everyone else and set the units to Millimeters and then scene scale to .001. This works to get things in and out at the right scale, however it screws up everything else blender does. Physics don't work, camera properties are wrong, lighting doesn't work as expecting and so on.

So, I want to work to Blender scale...1 unit = 1 millimeter. I don't want to change the scale factor so all the systems in blender work as normal, but when getting objects in and out of blender I want them to be the correct scale. I would like to set the default scale factor to export at 1000 and import at .001, so when it gets inside blender or outside of blender it is correct. Many people are working on this so I don't want everyone to have to remember when to scale what by what, and instead just have these values be the default.

I have tried to use chatgpt to help me code an add on to do this but blender's default scaling of 1.0 on import or export persists. How can I fix this?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, what format are you importing from / exporting to ?

Comment: Mostly exporting to STL but also OBJ, FBX for export. For import all those same file types, and very often STEP. We use Stepper add-on for importing STEP files.